# Getting classcast error in using google addview services

Tags: android, adview

here is error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

**adview.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" >
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Problem in your activity code...to initialize layout object. Share your code from your activity..